# Using active on li labels?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have set up tabbed navigation using  ul li and labels. I have been trying to make my li labels highlight and stay highlighted when they have been clicked. As they are not set up as hrefs the usual active strategy is not working. Below is the structure:

```
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="labels">
        <label class="rounded" for="tab1" id="label1">Shipping</label>
        <label class="rounded" for="tab2" id="label2">Returns</label>
        <label class="rounded" for="tab3" id="label3">Sizing</label>
        <label class="rounded" for="tab4" id="label4">Contact Us</label>
        <label class="rounded" for="tab5" id="label5">Payment</label>
        <label class="rounded" for="tab6" id="label6">FAQ</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

The CSS used for focus is:

```
.tabs label:focus {
    background: #eeeeee;
}
```

So on hover it shows the correct colour. I just cannot get the colour to remain once clicked. Once this is resolved I would also like the first tab to be highlighted when a visitor first arrives on the page.

This page is built using bootstrap however I cannot use the bootstrap nav tabs or pills so had to use this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use `tab-index` in order to work with `:focus`

> Adding `tab-index` will make your element focusable.

1. If you want to highlight your first tab, then you can either give a class to the first tab

   .highlight{
     background: #eeeeee;
   }

or you can write

```
.tab label:first-child{
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

[**See JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2946z772/1/)

```css
.tabs label:focus, .tabs label:hover{
    background: #eeeeee;
}
.tabs label{
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="labels">
        <label class="rounded" tabindex="0" for="tab0" id="label0">Shipping</label>
        <label class="rounded" tabindex="2" for="tab2" id="label2">Returns</label>
        <label class="rounded" tabindex="3" for="tab3" id="label3">Sizing</label>
        <label class="rounded" tabindex="4" for="tab4" id="label4">Contact Us</label>
        <label class="rounded" tabindex="5" for="tab5" id="label5">Payment</label>
        <label class="rounded" tabindex="6" for="tab6" id="label6">FAQ</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Made a mistake there. I am not using focus I am using hover and that works a charm. Its getting the background colour to remain when the user clicks the tab. Like the a:active for hrefs.

Are you saying by making those changes that this will achieve this? Going to try. :)

Comment: You can combine the hover and focus state like this - 
.tabs label:focus, .tabs label:hover{
    background: #eeeeee;
}

see the updated snippet.

Comment: Ah! That works a charm! Would you have any idea on how to make the first tab already be set on focus?

Comment: @Andrew Hi, yes. Answer is updated again. please have a look :)

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2946z772/

Comment: That works like a dream except that it stays focused even when clicking onto the next tab.

Comment: @Andrew Yup it will. CSS have some limitations. In this case, you need to use JavaScript to listen to the click events and change the background-color with respect to clicks. I will give one fiddle in a minute.

Comment: Thanks Jinu it's working great now. I am not able to use javascript on this template and will just forgo that extra functionality. :)

Comment: @Andrew : Alright. anyway, here is a fiddle using small code of jquery for any references https://jsfiddle.net/2946z772/2/. Please consider upvote/ marking my answer as accepted if your problem is solved. Thanks :)

Comment: I've just signed up and says I need 15 reputation before my vote shows publicly. :)